# Raycast, ссылка на последний объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Светим лучом на объект. Вопрос: как получить ссылку на этот объект, когда луч перестает на него светить?

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
{  
    obj = hit.collider.gameObject;  
    // действие с объектом
}
else
{       
    // ссылка на объект теряется
}
```

К примеру, светим на объект, получаем его компонент и меняем его цвет. Потом убираем луч и нужно поменять цвет обратно.

Comment: Создайте класс и статическое поле GameObject lastRaycastResult;  например, сохраняйте это поле а в if и считывайте в else

Comment: наверное, это самый простой рабочий вариант

Comment: Оформить как ответ?)

Comment: только зачем создавать еще один класс? ведь достаточно статического поля в этом же классе

Comment: это конечно не покрывает случай, когда луч с одного объекта сразу переходит на другой, более приближенное к реальности общее решение из ответа господина Александр Даниловский

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов, можно создать два списка объектов. В одном ("старом списке") будем хранить ссылки на объекты, полученный рейкастом в прошлый раз, а второй ("новый") список будем заполнять при текущем рейкасте.

После этого выполняем действия с объектами "нового" списка.

Затем пробегаем по всем элементам "старого списка" и ищем соответствующие объекты в "новом списке". Если совпадений нет - значит "луч перестает светить" - производим действия, которые необходимо произвести в данном случае.

После этого "старый список" заменяем значениями "нового", а "новый" очищаем.